# Split array by tag and delete all similar element

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex

I have some html page with text and need to output all inner HTML from tag b by alphabetical order in lower case. I'm just a begginer, so don't be strict.

My code is here (text is just for example): http://jsfiddle.net/pamjaranka/ebeptLzj/1/

Now I want to: 1) save upper case for inner HTML from tag abbr; 2) delete all similar element from the array (as MABs).

I was trying to find the way to split the array by tag, but all that I've done is:

```
for(var i=0; i<allbold.length; i++){
  labels[i] = allbold[i].innerHTML;
}
var searchTerm = ['abbr'];
var abbr = [];
var keywordIndex;
$.each(labels, function(i) {
  $.each(searchTerm, function(j) {
    var rSearchTerm = new RegExp('\\b' + searchTerm[j] + '\\b','i');
    if (labels[i].match(rSearchTerm)) {
      keywordIndex = i;
      for(var j=0; j<labels.length; j++){
        abbr[i] = labels[i];
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: whats your expected output should be ?

Comment: It should be: "advent, blog, ftp, HTML, MABs, WWW"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vanilla JS solution (no library required, [see jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ebeptLzj/2/)):

```
var allbold = document.querySelectorAll("b"),
    words = document.querySelector("#words"),
    labels = {}, i, word, keys, label;

// first, collect all words in an object (this eliminates duplicates)
for(i = 0; i < allbold.length; i++) {
    word = allbold[i].textContent.trim();
    if (word === 'Labels:') continue;
    labels[word.toLowerCase()] = word;
}

// then sort the object keys and output the words in original case
keys = Object.keys(labels).sort();
for(i = 0; i < keys.length; i++){
    label = document.createTextNode("SPAN");
    label.textContent = labels[keys[i]];
    words.appendChild(label);
    // add a comma if necessary
    if (i < keys.length - 1) {
        words.appendChild(document.createTextNode(", "));
    }
}
```

with one helper:

```
String.prototype.trim = function () {
    return this.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, "");
};
```

---

jQuery solution ([see jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ebeptLzj/3/)):

```
$(".content b").map(function () {
    return $("<span>", {text: $.trim(this.textContent)})[0];
}).unique(function () {
    return lCaseText(this);
}).sort(function (a, b) {
    return lCaseText(a) < lCaseText(b) ? -1 : 1;
}).appendTo("#words");
```

with two helpers:

```
$.fn.extend({
    unique: function (keyFunc) {
        var keys = {};
        return this.map(function () {
            var key = keyFunc.apply(this);
            if (!keys.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                keys[key] = true;
                return this;
            }
        });
    }
});

function lCaseText(element) {
    return element.textContent.toLowerCase();
}
```

Comment: Wow! That exactly that I want. I need some time to understand everything from your code. But thanks a lot!

Comment: @Ana The jQuery solution shows off a few features of jQuery (fluent interface, HTML creation, custom plugins) along with some advanced CSS usage to add commas in the right places. There's a lot of stuff to dabble with.

Answer (score 0):

use the mapping element Is [THIS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/3shsfsns/) for all upper case else [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3shsfsns/1/) after your comment what you need

```
 var maplabels = [];
 for(var i=0; i<allbold.length; i++){
if (allbold[i].innerHTML != "Labels:") {
    if(maplabels.indexOf(allbold[i].innerHTML) == -1){
        maplabels.push(allbold[i].innerHTML);
        labels.push('<i>' + allbold[i].innerHTML.toUpperCase() + '</i>');
    }


}
```

}

Comment: But if I add one more word "Until", output will be "FTP,HTML,WWW,MABs,Until,advent,blog". While I need: "advent,blog,ftp,HTML,MABs,until,WWW".
All in lower case except abbr.
http://jsfiddle.net/pamjaranka/z73d4a2n/

Comment: can jquery be used in your application ?